# In Tiptap, how do I get the html for the cursor selected area?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tiptap, prose-mirror

I have developed a rich text editor using tiptap/react. When I select a piece of text with the cursor, how do I get the html or json of the selected area?

For example, the following text, 'say-as' is a custom tag, I want to get it when the cursor is selected, but now I can only get plain text:

editor content:
`This shop has <say-as interpret-as="cardinal">100</say-as> customers every day`

I want to get labeled content when the cursor is selected，I try to do that：

`const { from, to } = editor.state.selection; const text = editor.state.doc.textBetween(from, to);`

but I can only get plain text now:

`This shop has 100 customers every day`

, this only retrieves plain text and does not contain the tags defined by the custom extension.

I appreciate your help！

Answer (score 0):

I would like to start by saying that ProseMirror (which TipTap extends), believes in a near complete separation of the browser dom, and the text document. Only acknowledging the dom enough to render and keep the 2 in sync.

That said ProseMirror/TipTap provide no such functionality. However, you can still do this with plain Javascript using [window.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection).

Comment: We can get the nodes from the selection, get the node's content in JSON format and then use `generateHTML` method from tiptap core - that's it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I finally fulfilled the requirement. First I get the start and end positions of selection. Then get the JSON tree of all the content through editor.getJSON and traverse the tree. The html structure of the area selected by the cursor is obtained by comparing the selection position